# Opencart : How To Load Different CSS Style, Based On Language

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart-3

I use opencart
I want to load stylesheet-rtl.css when language is ar
and stylesheet.css when language is en

i tried this and some others i found in internet but it doesn't work ?

```
<?php if($direction == "rtl"){?>
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/tt_palora1/stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php } else { ?>
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/tt_palora1/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php }?>
```

any help please ?

Comment: You were born with php skills ?

Comment: i'm front-end dev , but today i have the qustion above ! there is any prob ? . answer me if you can

Comment: Please table the [tour] and read [ask]. We arte not a codeing service. One hint: to output something in php use `echo`.

Comment: read above i said "any help please ?" but you came here like you were born with php skills

Comment: i tried many answers i found in internet , but it dosent work , read above i said i have tried many ... , you think i'm here to lose  my time?

Comment: i tried this , but it is for opencart 2.2 .. now it is 3.*

Comment: i tried but it looks like there is a problem in php codes 
bcuz i always get this the top of the header
-----------
data['language']; ?> echo ''; echo '';
------------

Comment: I looked up their [forum](http://forum.opencart.com) and it seems some things have changed. No more need for the code to get the language. You should search/ask there. If you find a solution, please share it here.

Comment: ok thank you bro i will search there

Comment: You're welcome @anton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `direction` variable in `header.php`:

```
$data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');
```

You can use it in your view file, **edit this file**:

```
catalog\view\theme\your-theme\template\common\header.twig
```

**Find:**

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/your-theme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Replace it with:**

```
{% if direction == 'rtl' %}
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/your-theme/stylesheet/stylesheet-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% else %}
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/your-theme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endif %}
```

Then clear your theme and ocmod caches.

Comment: up-voted, because that looks rather plausible to me.

Comment: Nice, solutions for Opencart 3 seem to be rare at this time and the older ones don't work anymore. This should be helpful for other tpp. I hope OP nozices this as he was frustrated and I was not very helpful on this.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<link href="catalog/view/theme/your-theme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">    
{% if direction == 'rtl' %}
    <link href="catalog/view/theme/your-theme/stylesheet/stylesheet-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
{% endif %}
```

`

in stylesheet-rtl.css just add what will change in RTL version so you get smaller file size